# Get a Screenshot of the Desktop through SSH on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

So I have an SSH session to a windows XP box via WinSSHD (from Ubuntu). I coded up a small Python program to take a screenshot with pywin32. Everything works fine when I run the script on the XP box directly in a normal 'desktop' session but if I SSH in and run the script the script fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                   
  File "ss.py", line 38, in <module>                                                                                 
    win32_ss()                                                                                                       
  File "ss.py", line 19, in win32_ss                                                                                 
    cDC.BitBlt((0, 0),(w, h) , dcObj, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)                                                      
win32ui.error: BitBlt failed
```

I am assuming this is because the SSH session is a different session than the XP session and has no access to the 'desktop' display device. I found reference on how to do this (I think this is what I want to do) in linux:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 import -window root /tmp/shot.png
```

I suppose what I'm looking for is how to do this in windows. Again, I'm using Python and can install any module needed. I currently am using pywin32 as this is much faster than PIL.

Answer (score 0):

I think SSH is the problem. I am not sure if SSH is the best way to do this. The best way would be to do the screenshot work at Windows' end. I have done something similar recently. I wanted to take a screenshot of a webpage opened in Internet Explorer and I am using Selenium Webdriver for this purpose with Python bindings for it.

What I did was that I decided to do it with the help of TCP sockets. I just wrote a very simple Python script that opens a TCP socket on the Windows machine and listens for connections. As soon as it receives the connection, it does the work of taking the screenshot. So in your case, it can take the screenshot there and save it locally and then the script can SSH to the system where you want this file to be.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I ended up creating a little "screenshot server" with zeromq to sit on the 'desktop' session and send out screenshots when requested. Would be easier (and faster I think) to use zeromq's IPC but it's not supported on windows so it has to use localhost TCP. Anywho, thanks for the input!